# How can I rewrite this code to work for every $n$

Tags: list-manipulation

I wanted to write this code in such a way that I run the whole thing for each $n$, and not write `a1 a2 a3` or `eq1 eq2 eq3` every time.

```
Clear[y, x, M, V, th, EI, PE]
y = a4*x^4 + a3*x^3 + a2*x^2;
th = D[y, x];
M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}];
V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}];
PE = EI/2*Integrate[D[y, {x, 2}]^2, {x, 0, L}] + P*(y /. x -> L);
Eq2 = D[PE, a2];
Eq1 = D[PE, a3];
Eq3 = D[PE, a4]
Sol = Solve[{Eq1 == 0, Eq2 == 0, Eq3 == 0}, {a3, a2, a4}];
y = y /. Sol[[1]];
th /. Sol[[1]];
FullSimplify[M /. Sol[[1]]]
FullSimplify[V /. Sol[[1]]]
```

---

Here's my attempt but it doesn't work:

```
Clear[a, y, x, M, V, th, EI, PE]
n = 4
y = Sum[{y^i}*a[i], {i, 0, n}]
th = D[y, x];
M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}];
V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}];
PE = EI/2*Integrate[D[y, {x, 2}]^2, {x, 0, L}] + P*(y /. x -> L)
Eq = Table [{D[PE, a[i]]}, {i, 2, n}]
Sol = Solve[{Eq[i] == 0}, {a[i]}];
y = y /. Sol[[1]];
th /. Sol[[1]];
FullSimplify[M /. Sol[[1]]]
FullSimplify[V /. Sol[[1]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful not to define things recursively like `y`. Use `Array[a, n]` to produce the list `{a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}`. You also do not need some of the lists `{...}` like in your `Table` and `Solve`, and you can use `ConstantArray` to make your zero vector for the equations:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
n = 4;
y = Sum[x^i*a[i], {i, 0, n}]
th = D[y, x];
M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}];
V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}];
PE = EI/2*Integrate[D[y, {x, 2}]^2, {x, 0, L}] + P*(y /. x -> L)
Eq = Table[D[PE, a[i]], {i, 2, n}]
sol = Solve[Eq == ConstantArray[0, n - 1], Array[a, n]]
y /. sol
th /. sol
Eq /. sol
FullSimplify[M /. sol[[1]]]
FullSimplify[V /. sol[[1]]]

(* {{a[2] -> -((L P)/(2 EI)), a[3] -> P/(6 EI), a[4] -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: Thanx, a lot I'm really new in this do you know where can I learn these simple codes more?

Comment: @AliAlCapone no problem. Please upvote/accept if you find it useful. You may be interested in this since you're new to Mathematica: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users

Comment: I did Thanx :-)

Comment: +1 You can simplify the `Solve` statement to `sol = Solve[Eq == 0,  Array[a, n]]`.  `Solve` will treat the `0` as if it were a vector. Also, the warning message can be avoided with `sol=Solve[Eq==0, Rest@Array[a, n]]`

Comment: is it possible in Mathematica to write an Array for n a plot the result for different n, so that I can compare every Plot with the others to compare? it is easy to do in python or Matlab but I'm a little childe in Mathematica

Comment: @AliAlCapone which variables do you want to plot for different n?

Comment: @flinty I want to plot M, V and Y

Comment: @AliAlCapone Do you want to plot M vs. x, V vs. x, and Y vs. x for various n ? In which case you need to provide values for EI , L, and P. Also the solution applied to Y is has floating a[0] and a[1]  because sol only provides values for some of the a[i], so it doesn't make sense to plot `-((L P x^2)/(2 EI)) + (P x^3)/(6 EI) + a[0] + x a[1]`

Comment: @flinty M vs. x, V vs. x, and Y vs. x for various n. and i change it a little because a[0] and a[1] are 0  ```Remove["Global`*"] n = 4; y = Sum[x^i*a[i], {i, 2, n}]; th = D[y, x]; M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}]; V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}]; PE = EI/2*Integrate[D[y, {x, 2}]^2, {x, 0, L}] + P*(y /. x -> L); Eq = Table[D[PE, a[i]], {i, 1, n}]; sol = Solve[Eq == 0, Array[a, n]] y /. sol th /. sol Eq /. sol; FullSimplify[M /. sol[[1]]] FullSimplify[V /. sol[[1]]] EI = 100; P = 1; L = 10; Plot[{V, -100, 100}, {x, 0, L}, AxesLabel -> {"x (m)", "M (N.m.)"},   PlotLegends -> {Style[" M", Bold, 12]}]```